# I keep getting Server Error

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I keep getting this error:

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

I'm using Java to get about 16 000 rows of data from Cloud SQL and the error is a 500 error.
I'm using GSON to convert the SQL Query into JSON, then I pass it as plain text.

What can I do to avoid this problem? Is there a better way of handling such a request?

Comment: I need more detail than this before I can help. Does it happen all the time or infrequently? Are you running on App Engine? Can you do it from `gcloud`? What's your connection string look like? Do you do retries? With such an unspecific message, I can't begin to help yet :( When we find out, I'll see if I can make the messaging better for this error.

Comment: This is my code in the doPost method in Android for Servlet: http://cl.ly/image/0Z0e3B0B0X0T

I get the same Server error every time I do this request, both in the appspot.com page and inside my Android application. If I change the query to return for example 4000 entries, it works. It looks like it's due to the size or length of the response.

Comment: It's a holiday here in the USA, so I'm off work. It's possible there is a data limit somewhere in the pipeline I can go looking for (but it's unlikely I can change it if it exists), which I will do on Monday. To get you up and running right now, I would add a limit to your statement: http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm . You can wrap the code in a for loop that iterates through limits of say, 0,999, | 1000, 1999 until the ResultSet.next() returns false before you've read all you expected. You could also try changing `fetchSize`, but your driver doesn't have to respect it.

Comment: Hi Samyboy89, can you contact me at cloud-sql@google.com with your instance name and a complete stack trace. "Server Error" makes it sound like you are seeing an HTTP error, but you seem to be connecting to Cloud SQL via a MySQL driver, which wouldn't give the error message you are describing. I don't have enough here to join the dots :(